# Github deployment 404 on refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I've tried following this guide https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

I've included in `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/my-app/'
      : '/'
  }
```

Seems to work when I've deployed this to my Gh, but whenever I press F5 on any page, I get 404:

```
404
File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.
```

Comment: are you using routes lazy loading?

Comment: No, standard imports

Comment: It means that your page has not been deployed. You are sure that you have added script correctly to actually build your project e.g. deploy.sh as mentioned in step 2 of link provided here.